# Login in Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am beginner in Laravel. I use in my project Laravel 5.8.

I use Laravel login system in my project.

I have my user migration:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->bigInteger('company_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('companies')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->char('enable', 1)->default(0);
            $table->char('demo_mode', 1)->default(0);
            $table->date('account_paid_for');
            $table->string('name', 120)->nullable();
            $table->string('surname', 120)->nullable();
            $table->string('email', 120)->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('url_address', 160);
            $table->text('content')->nullable();
            $table->dateTime('last_activity')->nullable();
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->engine = "InnoDB";
            $table->charset = 'utf8mb4';
            $table->collation = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci';
        });
```

I need to change Laravel's default login to verify that enable = 1

Only users with enable = 1 can log in. How to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an after middleware or just override the authenticated method within your LoginController:

```
use Auth; // add this at the top

protected function authenticated( Request $request, $user )
{
    if( ! $user->enable) {
        Auth::logout(); // log out the user

        return back()->with('error', 'The user is not allowed to enter');
    }

    return redirect($this->redirectTo);
}
```